# Using MessageBodyReader for multiple parameters in RESTful services

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

The following method does not allow my servlet container to start:

```
@PUT
public String upload(final Customer customer, final Control control) {
  // ...
}
```

I get, not surprisingly:

```
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method ... at index 0
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method ... index 1
SEVERE: Method, ..., is not recognized as valid resource method.
```

I have implemented MessageBodyReaders for each type. Removing any of the parameters enables the servlet container to start gracefully, so I suspect there must be a restriction on the number of parameters that will be resolved via Entity-Providers.

The problem is that I *NEED* these two parameters, since I am providing both SOAP and REST support, and of course, I am not in the liberty of changing method signatures, and I also do not want to create one specific Jersey method and one specific JAX-WS method as entry points.

I'm using Jersey 1.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAX-RS allows only one entity parameter. The reson is very simple: each request may have at most one  body (multiparts are not supported by spec)
So you must create two methods.
Btw, I don't think it's a good practice to mix JAXRS and JAXWS in the same class.

Comment: Right... A possible way is to clump together `Customer` and `Control` into a `CustomerWithControl` class, then internally call the method that accepts separate `Customer` and `Control` as parameters.